# How to install every package from A custom Repository?

Tags: apt

I made my own custom repository for my network.

How do you install EVERYTHING from a repository?

Is it something like:

```
sudo apt-get install -y MYREPO:*
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install -y *
```

Answer (score 1):

You need aptitude for this task (it could be done with other tools but I find this one easier):

```
sudo aptitude install '?origin(the.origin.name)'
```

Done,